# Unmanaged package missing standard field picklist while packaging

Tags: custom-button, picklist, unmanaged-package

While creating a unmanaged package from sandbox, some custom stuffs are not deployed.

a) Its missing order status custom picklist values.

b) Custom Action link and buttons are not set by default to list views.

c) Standard object layout customization are not available in package.

Created Package by Setup package widget & manually selected every component.
Is these a right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - these components that you've mentioned are not package'able. They should be applied as post-install manual steps.

Comment: Is there any post deployment script like procedure to try out to solve this problem?